# Would my postgresql trigger slows down my insert

Tags: postgresql, timescaledb

I'm building up a trigger to track the latest timestamp for each symbol coming into my table for postgresql/ timescaleDB.

The table creation definition looks like the following

```
create table symbol_cache (
  symbol text not null primary key,
  timestamp timestamptz not null
)

create or replace function refresh_symbol_cache() returns trigger
    language plpgsql
as $$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO symbol_cache (symbol, timestamp)
    VALUES (
               NEW.symbol,
               NEW.timestamp
           )
    ON CONFLICT (symbol)
        DO UPDATE SET
                      symbol = NEW.symbol,
                      timestamp = GREATEST(old.timestamp, new.timestamp);
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$;

create trigger update_symbol_cache
    after insert or update
    on db_009a005a_df_downloaded_grand
    for each row
execute procedure refresh_symbol_cache();
```

Basically, I would like to ask after I added such trigger, would my insertion speed into db_009a005a_df_downloaded_grand became noticeably slower?

Comment: Some issues: 1) Don't name your fields with a reserved word e.g. "timestamp". 2) `GREATEST(old.timestamp, new.timestamp);` is going to fail on an `INSERT` as there is no `OLD` record on an insert. 3) No need for `symbol = NEW.symbol,`. If you get to the `CONFLICT` it will be on `symbol` so you know it is already the correct one. Once you get these ironed out, try the trigger out and see what the overhead is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a trigger will measurably slow down data modification speed. There is no such thing as a free lunch.